# Avoid the 'seq' command in Bash?

Tags: bash, seq

I'm having a discussion about the use of `seq` for small loop in a Bash script (for example a loop with 10 iterations).
I say, for example, is better do this

```
for i in {1..10}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

than use *seq*

```
for i in $(seq 10)
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

as written here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

In my opinion is useless for short loop use a not a built-in command. What about performance for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seq` comes handy when you do not know the range you are about to perform: you can say `seq $a $b`, whereas you cannot say `{$a..$b}`.

Also, `{}` is available just for Bash, so in for example Shell you won't be able to use it.

That being said, if you are targeting bash then using `{1..10}` is certainly going to be faster (and cheaper) than using `seq` and that can matter. `seq` is an external command, and that makes the execution slower.

From `man bash`:

> **Brace Expansion**
>
> *Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions*, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. 
>   It is strictly textual.  Bash does not apply any syntactic
>   interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the
>   braces.
>
> ...
>
> *Brace expansion introduces a slight incompatibility with historical versions of sh.  sh does not treat opening or closing braces specially
>   when they appear as part of a word, and preserves them in the output*.
>   Bash removes braces from words as a consequence of brace expansion. 
>   For example, a word entered to sh as file{1,2} appears identically in
>   the output.  The same  word is output as file1 file2 after expansion
>   by bash.  If strict compatibility with sh is desired, start bash with
>   the +B option or disable brace expansion with the +B option to the set
>   command.

Comment: That being said if you are targeting bash then using `{1..10}` is certainly going to be faster (and cheaper) than using `seq` and that can matter.

Comment: You nailed it, @EtanReisner, I just appended your comment to the answer :)

Comment: So better to do `for ((n=1; n<=10; n++))` ?
And so the problem could be with a large loop, not short ?

Comment: @Kyrol no, use `{a..b}`  whenever it is possible. The problem could be if your range is not fixed; then, you cannot use `{..}` because it does not admit variables.

Comment: Ok so the better solution is the first that I write, but if you don't know the range of a loop, you have to use `seq`.
Is there other solution instead of seq ? What is your favourite?

Comment: @Kyrol Yep! I don't like the `for` syntax in Bash, I find `seq` quite easier to write, so this is the one I use. And of course `{a..b}` if I know `a` and `b` beforehand :)

Comment: I post this question because in the link I putted, below the seq example, you can read:
*There is no good reason to use an external command such as seq to count and increment numbers in the for loop, hence it is recommend that you avoid using seq. The builtin command are fast.*

Comment: @Kyrol Yes, this is true. So my usage of `seq` over `for` is bad in terms of performance. It would be best to use `for ((n=$a; n<=$b; n++))` instead of `seq $a $b`. This is because, as you note from the link, executing a builtin is faster than calling an external command. However, as always it is good to check when to worry a lot about performance and when it is just a matter of characters you want to type in your script.